# Parallelization of loop with multiple arguments python

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a loop that takes minimum 2 hours to run, so I decided to parallelize it. I never paralleled with python but heard `multiprocessing` is reliable therefore I tried it but when I try to use `starmap` it outputs  `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)`

The code is down below :

```
def main():
    EXR_2_JPG()
    arg1 = "validation/Church/Image_0.png"
    arg2 = "validation/Church/Image_1.png"
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(compare,zip(arg1,arg2))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Basically the `compare` function is a disparity map calculator so compare(img1,img2) will take the path and turn them to arrays then will loop inside to calculate the disparity that's why it takes a long time. so i want to parallelize it

I also tried to use `map` but it only works with 1-argument also adding `itertools.repeat` and `functools.partial` .

The output is :

```
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

The sequential main is :

```
def main():
    EXR_2_JPG()
    arg1 = "validation/Church/Image_0.png"
    arg2 = "validation/Church/Image_1.png"
    compare(arg1,arg2)
```

i tired to create another function just for the the double loop but now i get an error of `TypeError: starmap() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 10 were given`

```
def loop_f(milieu,rows1,columns1,img1,img2,search_range,sub,out):
    for i in trange(milieu,rows1-milieu):
        for j in trange(milieu,columns1-milieu):
            
            kernel_img1 = img1[i-milieu:i+milieu-1,j-milieu:j+milieu-1,0:3]        
            for w in range (j,min([j+search_range,columns1-milieu])):
                kernel_img2 = img2[i-milieu:i+milieu-1,w-milieu:w+milieu-1,0:3]
                #print(np.sum(kernel_img1),np.sum(kernel_img2))
                testered = tester(kernel_img1)
                testered2 = tester(kernel_img2)
                sum1 = np.sum(kernel_img1)
                sum2 = np.sum(kernel_img2)
                sub[w-j] = np.abs(np.sum(kernel_img1 - kernel_img2))
            #print(sub)
            #print("///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////")
            indice_min = np.argmin(sub)
            out[i,j] = indice_min
    return out
```

and inside the `compare` function now i have this :

```
    with Pool() as pool:
        outx =pool.starmap(loop_f,milieu,rows1,columns1,img1,img2,search_range,sub,out)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: `zip(arg1, arg2)` will give you an iterator with items like `('v', 'v')`, `('a', 'a')`, `('l', 'l')`, ... Is that really what you intended?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: basically the compare function is a diparity calculator so ``compare(img1,img2)`` will take the path and turn them to arrays then will loop inside to calculate the disparity that's why it takes a long time

Comment: `zip` is the source of the error here, remove it so to only keep a tuple. That being said, a bigger issue is that there is only one big task and thus you cannot automagically parallelize a function call. You need multiple independent task to apply parallelism...

Comment: so if i create another function for the loop and use pool with it, it should work ?

Comment: i tired to create another function just for the the double loop but now i get an error of ``TypeError: starmap() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 10 were given``